# A political ideology that combines ideas of others to solve problems at hand?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

I'm looking for an existing word or neologism to name a political ideology that uses principles and ideas of others.

The goal of this ideology is mix and combine approaches in order to best reply to problems experienced in society.

Alternatively, as this is for fiction the issue with such an ideology is that it might end up being corrupted so if you have any ideas for a second word for an approach that would exist independently of parties and ideologies then feel free to formulate one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the existing term would be *eclectic* - drawing ideas from different places.

Comment: So eclectism? It seems the word exists :)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eclecticism

Comment: A politician who routinely uses ideas from other parties because they *work* (rather than because they arise naturally within the context of his own professed ideology) is often called a ***pragmatist*** (except by people who disagree with him, who'll probably call him an opportunist, populist, or turncoat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a two-party system as in the U.S., you could consider using "[bipartisanship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartisanship)" which means:

> a political situation, especially in the context of a two-party
>   system, as is the case for countries such as the United States, in
>   which opposing political parties find common ground through
>   compromise, in theory.

The word "multipartisanship" is not broadly used and I would be reluctant to use this word unless there is enough context to support it.

The best word that could describe your context is [*eclecticism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclecticism) as commented by @WS2.

> Eclecticism is a conceptual approach that does not hold rigidly to a
>   single paradigm or set of assumptions, but instead draws upon multiple
>   theories, styles, or ideas to gain complementary insights into a
>   subject, or applies different theories in particular cases. However,
>   this is often without conventions or rules dictating how or which
>   theories were combined.

[Wikipedia]

Comment: Thanks :) . Btw, multipartisan does exist. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multipartisan